# 'Rendering' tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I feel that this tag is not needed. Whenever it has been used so far, it's also accompanied with the tag for the render engine. Such as [cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cycles) [yafaray](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yafaray) [freestyle](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freestyle). Shouldn't we just get rid of it? See for yourself: [rendering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rendering)

Comment: it can be useful.. say for discussing rendering techniques/theory etc..

Comment: @iKlsR good point.

Comment: @iKlsR but I think that if a question has a rendering engine tag, that it shouldn't have the rendering tag.

Answer (score 5):

We should keep the [rendering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rendering) tag.

Comment: I personally prefer this option, by the way.

Answer (score 3):

We should keep the `rendering` tag.

Although many questions regarding rendering are specific to a particular engine, there are still a good number of questions that might arise independent of the rendering engine, or questions that ask for comparisons between the different engines. Also, there are a number of features of the rendering process that are general enough that even if the user is working with one engine, the answers might still be useful in a different engine (such as speed/optimization questions).

Comment: Also, since tag nesting is not currently supported, if I'm looking for wide-range questions on rendering, I wouldn't want to go through all tags, having one is helpful

Answer (score 1):

We should keep the [rendering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rendering), but remove it from every question that already has a rendering engine tag.

Answer (score -3):

We should get rid of the [rendering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rendering) tag.

Comment: why do you have two different answers?

Comment: @iKlsR He wants rep.

Comment: @iKlsR, I've seen this done quite often on several different other SE sites I'm a part of, mainly just to make it easy for the community to choose the option they like best.

Comment: @Dan the Man, no, you can't get rep from the meta site.

Comment: @PeterCassetta Ah ok. Didn't know.